# Find a solution for the equation $a(4n) = {a(n)\over 4}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I was given the equation $a(4n) = {a(n)\over 4}$ where $a(1) = 1$. I know that ${1\over \sqrt n }$ solves this equation, but I don't know how I would find this solution by hand if I didn't know about it.
Any hints on this matter are greatly appreciated.
EDIT: oh snap I made a typo. It is  $a(4n) = {a(n)\over 2}$. I apologize for my mistake.

I'm not sure why my question was put on hold. To clarify, I was asking how one would systematically solve the recursive equation given above, as I was only able to see the solution, but not how one would find it.
Anyway, my question has been answered by eranreches (do I need to something else apart from selecting the best answer to mark the question as answered?  -- if I have to, I'm sorry, it is my first time posting here...)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What is the equation?

Comment: $\frac 1{\sqrt n}$ does not solve your recurrence.  With that definition, $a_1=1$ but $a_4=\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu Isn't $a_4 = 1/4$?

Comment: @yanko  I took the OP's comment to propose $a_n=\frac 1{\sqrt n}$.  as a solution.  Using that definition, I'd conclude that $a_4=\frac 1{\sqrt 4}=\frac 12$.  As I said, that is not compatible with the given recurrence.  Perhaps something else was intended.

Comment: Note that $a(n) = c/n$ is a solution.  I found this by assuming that $a(n) = n^p$, and then solving $4^p = 1/4$.  I'm not sure if this is the only solution, though.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry, I made a typo. I meant to write $a(4n)={a(n)\over 2}$

Comment: In that case, if you assume $a_n=n^k$ then you quickly get $k=-\frac 12$.  But you need more initial conditions to prove that this is the only answer.  you could have $a_n=\frac 1{\sqrt n}$ for $n\in \{1,4,16,\cdots\}$  but $a_n=\frac c{\sqrt n}$ for other $n$.

Comment: @loungelizard i THINK IT WAS ON because your question was not so clear and you did not give any attempt from your side

Comment: @GuyFsone oh yeah, well that makes sense. I totally forgot to include my attempts. I tried throwing generating functions and the standard algorithm for solving homogenous recurrence relations at it, but the non-linear dependence really broke everything I tried. I'll make sure to include my attempts in any future questions I might have. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more systematic way, define

$$b_{n}\equiv a_{4^{n}}$$

Then

$$b_{0}=a_{1}=1$$

$$b_{n+1}=a_{4^{n+1}}=a_{4\cdot4^{n}}=\frac{a_{4^{n}}}{2}=\frac{b_{n}}{2}$$

with a solution $b_{n}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. Now reverse to get

$$a_{n}=b_{\log_{4}n}=\frac{1}{2^{\log_{4}n}}=\frac{1}{4^{\frac{1}{2}\log_{4}n}}=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

as wanted.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=4^k$, so that $4n=4^{k+1}$, and let $b(k):=a(2^k)=a(n)$.

Now

$$b(k+1)=\frac{b(k)}2,$$ which is an ordinary recurrence, with the particular solution (fulfilling $b(0)=1$)

$$b(k)=\frac 1{2^k}=\frac 1{\sqrt n}=a(n).$$